# Populate form fields from a json file when user inputs a value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

i want to fetch bank name, branch, city and district from a json array

[image]

here is my results.json file

```
    {
    "ifsc": [{
            "ifsc": "PUNB0000100",
            "bank": "PUNJAB NATIONAL BANK",
            "city": "ABOHAR",
            "branch": "ABOHAR MAIN",
            "district": "FEROZEPUR "
        }]
}
```

Comment: How you got the result.json? At least, please show us how you got json data, and when to populate the data. The are many confusion right now in head.

Comment: i created json data from a mysql table,i want that when a user input ifsc code all the remaining fields in the form will populate which belong to that ifsc code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my results.json file

```
{
    "PUNB0000100": {
        "bank": "PUNJAB NATIONAL BANK",
        "city": "ABOHAR",
        "branch": "ABOHAR MAIN",
        "district": "FEROZEPUR "
    },
    "PUNB0000200": {
        "bank": "PUNJAB NATIONAL BANK",
        "city": "SIROHI",
        "branch": "ABU ROAD",
        "district": "SIROHI"
    }
}
```

here is my javascript code

```
<script type="text/javascript">        
    $("document").ready(function(){

            $(function () {
            $.getJSON('results.json')
              .done(function (data) {
              var ents={list:data};


            $("#ifsc2").blur(function(){
                var ifsc1 = $('#ifsc1').val();
                //console.log(ents.list[ifsc2].city);
                $('#branch_name').val(ents.list[ifsc2].branch)
                $('#branch_address').val(ents.list[ifsc2].district)
             });

        });
           }); //end of $(function)
    });//end of ready
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like the below should work for you:

```js
var object = {
    "ifsc": [{
        "ifsc": "PUNB0000100",
            "bank": "PUNJAB NATIONAL BANK",
            "city": "ABOHAR",
            "branch": "ABOHAR MAIN",
            "district": "FEROZEPUR "
    }]
}
$('.fillMe:eq(0)').val( object.ifsc[0].ifsc );
$('.fillMe:eq(1)').val( object.ifsc[0].bank );
$('.fillMe:eq(2)').val( object.ifsc[0].city );
$('.fillMe:eq(3)').val( object.ifsc[0].branch );
$('.fillMe:eq(4)').val( object.ifsc[0].district );
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="fillMe" value=""/><br>
<input class="fillMe" value=""/><br>
<input class="fillMe" value=""/><br>
<input class="fillMe" value=""/><br>
<input class="fillMe" value=""/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Kindly look at the following sample code, after entering IFSC code onblur data will be populated in  their respected fields.

```js
var bankdata = {
    "ifsc": [
        {
            "ifsc": "PUNB0000100",
            "bank": "PUNJAB NATIONAL BANK",
            "city": "ABOHAR",
            "branch": "ABOHAR MAIN",
            "district": "FEROZEPUR "
        },
        {
            "ifsc": "HDFC0000101",
            "bank": "HDFC BANK",
            "city": "Hyd",
            "branch": "HYD MAIN",
            "district": "RR"
        }
    ]
}
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#Ifsc').on('blur',function(){
        var Filter = [];
    var reqIfsc = $(this).val().toUpperCase();
        $.each(bankdata.ifsc,function(index,val){
            console.log(val.ifsc);
            if(val.ifsc == reqIfsc)
            {
                $('#Bankname').val(val.bank);
                $('#Branch').val(val.branch);
                $('#BranchAddress').val(val.city+","+val.district);
            }else{
                $('#Bankname').val('');
                $('#Branch').val('');
                $('#BranchAddress').val('');
            }
        })        
        
    });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
    <div>
    <label>* IFSC</label>
    <input type="text" id="ifsc"/>
    </div>
    <div>
    <label>* Bank Name</label>
    <input type="text" id="ifsc"/>
    </div>
    <div>
    <label>* Conform IFSC Code</label>
    <input type="text" id="ifsc"/>
    </div>
    <div>
    <label>* Branch</label>
    <input type="text" id="ifsc"/>
    </div>
    <div>
    <label>* Branch Address</label>
    <input type="text" id="ifsc"/>
    </div>
     <div>
    <label>* Transaction Id</label>
    <input type="text" id="ifsc"/>
    </div>
     <div>
    <label>* Conform Transaction Id</label>
    <input type="text" id="ifsc"/>
    </div>
    
</form>
```